# Datepicker for twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter, twitter-bootstrap

I have not found an existing datepicker on github or in the twitter bootstrap.

I have a modified version of the twitter bootstrap, with orange styled icons for buttons/themes.

When I attempt to use the [datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) from eyecon it remodels the icons as the color blue on my bootstrap website. I would like to set this datepicker as the same as my theme. But I'm not sure whether or not I should copy-paste from the eyecon version into my version?

Does someone know a better way on how I could restyle the datepicker from eyecon? for my theme? I'm not currently using any additional plugins.

---

Edit 4 september 2012

What I means in this question is something like using a plugin such as http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ The themes I am working on is based on Orange themes.

The eyecon have a themes in Blue color. My means to get the same plugin fit according to my orange theme.

Answer (score 1):

Datepicker from eyecon uses its own css file [datepicker.css](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css). You should change the colors in this css file to the colors you need.